# Stored procedure insert value using if else condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have written a stored procedure which is working fine. I want to calculate average of `fd.benefitscontributions` which i can do as `AVG(fd.benefitscontributions)` .

If the result is greater than 50 then insert 'good' else 'bad' in the  status column in the if_funddetails table. if_funddetails has 4 columns currently i am inserting values in three column but the forth column ,i.e, `status` value is based on the average of `fd.benefitscontributions`

```
 INSERT INTO if_funddetails  ( d.fundcode,   d.fundname, fd.benefitscontributions )
  SELECT DISTINCT  d.fundcode, d.fundname, fd.benefitscontributions
  FROM   dbo.ws_funddetail AS d 
         LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.v_fundnooutofpocket AS nop 
                      ON d.funddetailid = nop.funddetailid 
         INNER JOIN dbo.ws_funddata AS fd 
                 ON nop.fundreportid = fd.fundreportid
```

I can get the average but how to add value 'good' or 'bad' in the status column is not sure. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Use case statement with average

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Case statement with your AVG function, as you got AVG already

```
CASE WHEN AVG(FieldName)>50 THEN 'Good' ELSE 'Bad' END AS 'Status'
```

**Note:** To use aggregate function, you have to Group other columns

Answer (score 0):

Try this.. Case used to know the staus

```
    INSERT INTO IF_FUNDDETAILS  ( D.FUNDCODE,   D.FUNDNAME,  STATUS )
    SELECT DISTINCT  D.FUNDCODE, D.FUNDNAME, CASE WHEN  AVG( FD.BENEFITSCONTRIBUTIONS)>50 THEN 'GOOD' ELSE 'BAD' END AS STATUS
    FROM   DBO.WS_FUNDDETAIL AS D 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN DBO.V_FUNDNOOUTOFPOCKET AS NOP ON D.FUNDDETAILID = NOP.FUNDDETAILID 
    INNER JOIN DBO.WS_FUNDDATA AS FD ON NOP.FUNDREPORTID = FD.FUNDREPORTID 
    GROUP BY  D.FUNDCODE, D.FUNDNAME
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
IIF(AVG(FD.BENEFITSCONTRIBUTIONS)>50 ,'Good', 'Bad') AS 'Status'
```

Comment: `IFF` is SQL Server 2012+. Tags have [tag:sql-server-2008]